# qemu macos host ubuntu client copy and paste not working

Tags: macos, virtualization, qemu

i started an already installed qcow2 image as in https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-ubuntu-20-04/.
macos 11.0 host and ubuntu 2004 client.
Everything works fine. But i also need copy and paste throw vm and host. So i did an
`apt-get install qemu-guest-agent`
as descripted in https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu-guest-agent
But the
`systemctl start qemu-guest-agent`
failed because of
`a dependency job for qemu-guest-agent.service failed`
So what was going wrong? How can i enable copy and paste?

Comment: I don't know why, but it worked with an new qemu image and start with


...
    -chardev socket,path=/tmp/qga.sock,server,nowait,id=qga0 \
    -device virtio-serial \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0    
    

But copy and paste do not work. How can i enable copy and paste without spice on macos host and ubuntu guest?